# how can i write url in react-router v5 without repeating previous route?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, frontend

I have a problem with writing a good URL without rewriting and adding a new endpoint like this.

```
{
      path: '/admisi/rawat-darurat-igd',
      exact: true,
      sidebar: null,
      main: () => <> <RawatDaruratIGD/> </>
  },
  {
    path: '/admisi/rawat-darurat-igd/registrasi-igd-umum',
    sidebar: null,
    main: () => <> <h1>Ini Form</h1> </>
  }
```

when I'm adding a new route from

```
'/admisi/rawat-darurat-igd'
```

to new route

```
'/admisi/rawat-darurat-igd/registrasi-igd-umum'
```

I'm writing it with hardcode.

I want to cleaner write the URL code in react-router v5. how can I write URLs effectively?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What is the issue with using an absolute path?

Comment: there's no issue sir. but i'm feel tired when i rewrite the url again if i add new route

Comment: Well, a flat list structure of routes doesn't lend itself well to building relative to a parent value. You *could* do something like `const ROOT = "/admisi/rawat-darurat-igd";` and `path: ROOT,` and ```path: `${ROOT}/registrasi-igd-umum`,```, but I don't quite think that is what you are looking for.